# ASP.NET Core - How do Validate Required Fields in SOAP Web Service Request Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap

In ASP.NET Core-Web API, I am building a SOAP Web Service using SoapCore Package.

RequestMode:

```
[DataContract]
public class RequestModel
{
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; } = 88766.543233m;

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "String content";

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "String content";
}
```

ResponseModel:

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; } = 88766.543233m;

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "String content";

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "String content";
}
```

ApiResponse:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseDescription { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public ResponseModel Response { get; set; } // Added property

    public static ApiResponse Success(ResponseModel response, string message = "Request processed successfully")
    {
        return new ApiResponse
        {
            ResponseCode = "200",
            ResponseDescription = "Success",
            Message = message
        };
    }
    public static ApiResponse Failure(string message)
    {
        return new ApiResponse
        {
            ResponseCode = "500",
            ResponseDescription = "Failure",
            Message = message
        };
    }
}
```

Repository:

SoapRepository:

```
public class SoapRepository : ISoapRepository
{
    public Task<ApiResponse<ResponseModel>> ProcessRequest(RequestModel request)
    {
        try
        {
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(request);
            Validator.ValidateObject(request, validationContext, validateAllProperties: true);
            var processedResponse = new ResponseModel
            {
                Amount = request.Amount,
                FirstName = request.FirstName,
                LastName = request.LastName
            };
            return Task.FromResult(ApiResponse<ResponseModel>.Success(processedResponse));
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(ApiResponse<ResponseModel>.Failure(ex.Message));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(ApiResponse<ResponseModel>.Failure(ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class SoapProcessingService : ISoapProcessingService
{
    private readonly ISoapRepository _requestRepository;
    public SoapProcessingService(
        ISoapRepository requestRepository
        )
    {
        _requestRepository = requestRepository;
    }
    public async Task<ApiResponse> ProcessRequests(RequestModel request)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await _requestRepository.ProcessRequest(request);
            return response;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ApiResponse.Failure(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using SoapCore;
using SoapService.Api.Repositories.Implementations;
using SoapService.Api.Repositories.Interfaces;
using SoapService.Api.Services.Implementations;
using SoapService.Api.Services.Interfaces;

namespace SoapService.Api
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddSingleton<ISoapRepository, SoapRepository>();
                        services.AddTransient<ISoapProcessingService, SoapProcessingService>();
                    });

                    webBuilder.Configure(app =>
                    {
                        // Configure the middleware for SOAPCore
                        app.UseSoapEndpoint<ISoapProcessingService>("/Soap", new SoapEncoderOptions(), SoapSerializer.DataContractSerializer);

                        // Handle the default route
                        app.Run(async (context) =>
                        {
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync("SOAP Web Service is running.");
                        });
                    });
                })
                .Build();

            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

In SOAPUI, when I submitted the Request, I expected validation for required to occur. But this is not taking effect. No validation occurs.

How do I resolve this?